# Clock looping help in JAVA

Tags: java, clock

I need a little help on my clock problem. I'm getting confused with the logic. Basically, what I want to do is this.  If the given input is: `23:25:55`, when the second reaches `60`, it should become `00` and add `+1` to the minute. However, it prints `23:25:60` and only after pressing `OK` on Netbeans it becomes `23:26:00`. It would be better if the 60 doesn't appear anymore. Here are the methods that I have in my class.

```
public  void incHour(){
    hr++;

    if (hr == 24){
        hr = 0;
    }
    printTime();
}

public void incMinute(){
    min++;

    if (min > 59){
        incMinute();
        min = 0;
    }
    printTime();
}

public void incSecond(){
    sec++;

    if (min > 59){
        incMinute();
        sec = 0;
    }
    printTime();
}
```

Comment: Your `incMinute()` method is calling itself - it should be calling `incHour()`. Just a typo, basically.

Comment: your min>59 in  incSecond method is also a typo.??

Comment: I wasn't able to edit it.

Answer (score 2):

You have a bunch of copy&paste errors. In `incMinute()`, change to

```
if (min > 59){
    incHour(); //changed from incMinute();
```

and in `incSecond()`, change to

```
if (sec > 59){ //changed from if (min > 59){
    incMinute();
```

**EDIT**

> The 60 still shows up.

This is because when `sec > 59`, you increase it to 60 and then call `printTime()` from the `incMinute()` method too. Do the zeroing first, and add an `else` clause like this to only print it once. You will have to do the same alteration to your `incMinute()` method:

```
public void incSecond(){
    sec++;
    if (sec > 59){
        sec = 0;
        incMinute();
    } else {
        printTime();
    }
}
```

Comment: Oops. Sorry about that. I'll try this out.

Comment: @Ralphx3589: Added some additional help.

Answer (score 1):

You made a small typo:

```
public void incSecond(){
    sec++;

    if (min > 59){ // <- here replace by sec
        incMinute();
        sec = 0;
    }
    printTime();
}
```

Same with minute:

```
public void incMinute(){
    min++;

    if (min > 59){
        incMinute();// <- here, incHour
        min = 0;
    }
    printTime();
}
```

Why do you print the time every time? Normally output methods are separated from altering methods. That's the *Controller* pattern.